# PhpStorm indent multi-line array elements

Tags: php, coding-style, phpstorm

How to configure PhpStorm's PHP coding style settings so this code:

```
<?php

$array = [
'element1' => 'value1',
'element2' => 'value2',
'element3' => 'value3',
];
```

Is reformatted like this:

```
<?php

$array = [
    'element1' => 'value1',
    'element2' => 'value2',
    'element3' => 'value3',
];
```

Problem is that even if I format arrays like I want, any call to reformat option will "destroy" that formatting and bring me back to unindented elements.

I am interested in short array declaration only.

Comment: Please show your formatting settings for those elements.

Comment: There are 5 screens of settings. Which settings are relevant for this case?

Comment: Those that affect arrays + any indents.

Comment: Here are the settings: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdr7skgznrgl2ye/code-style.xml?dl=0 If I knew which exact settings affect this behavior and whether this particular use case is covered, I would not ask the question.

Comment: Please change `Continuation indent` from `0` to desired value (I guess it will be `4`, based on your code sample).

Comment: *"If I knew which exact settings affect this behavior..."* Arrays have only 2 sections that you can spot by their names (4 options at `Wrapping & Braces` tab and 3 at `Other` tab). This particular settings that I have mentioned in my previous comment is general (affect pretty much all elements) but still directly related to indents.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. 4 spaces is indentation that we want for everything, so it's perfectly fine that it is global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current code style: please change `Continuation indent` from `0` to the desired value (I guess it will be `4`, based on your code sample).

This can be done for all languages at once (`General` node) or just PHP.